# Can I loop a range of non consecutive cells i.e F35, F46, F54, F62....ect

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am attempting to loop a number of shapes to change color depending on whether there is a value >0 in a corresponding cell in another worksheet. Each next shape in the loop is a consecutive number but the corresponding cells are not i.e Shape 3 corresponds to F34, Shape 4 Corresponds to F46 ect. The problem is the non Consecutive Cells.

This is the Code I have at the Moment

```
Sub Shape_Color_Change()

Dim x As Integer

Dim y As Integer

y = Array(35 Or 46 Or 54 Or 62)

For x = 3 To 6

   If Worksheets("Cell").Cells(y, 35) > 0 Then

      Worksheets("Shape").Shapes(x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 51, 204)

   Else

      Worksheets("Shape").Shapes(x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 102, 102)

   End If

Next x

End Sub
```

It gives me run time error 13 at the moment but I've also got error 1004 attempting different approaches. This one seems the closest to me though.

Answer (score 2):

Use a proper array and loop through that. Your array should contain the pertinent cells so adjust to suit.

```
Sub Shape_Color_Change()

Dim x As Long

Dim y As Variant

y = Array("F34", "F46", "F54", "F62") 'zero-based

For x = 3 To 6
    If Worksheets("Cell").Range(y(x - 3)) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Shape").Shapes(x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 51, 204)
    Else
        Worksheets("Shape").Shapes(x).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(102, 102, 102)
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice method of handling the array indices.

Comment: Cheers Big help! Only discovered for Loops yesterday so I'm still Learning!

Comment: My pleasure. Thanks @Gary'sStudent.

Comment: @C.Lawn suggestion: define `Const rgbBrightBlue = &HCC3300` and `Const rgbDarkGrey = &H666666`, and replace the inlined `RGB` function calls with these constants.